# Where's the "review tag wiki" tool?

Tags: support, tags, tag-wiki

I posted a "proposed update" to the [mortgage tag wiki](https://money.stackexchange.com/tags/mortgage/info) yesterday, and got a message that it would display after being peer reviewed.

I've also noticed that I have the [approve tag wiki edits](https://money.stackexchange.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) privilege, but I have no idea how to use it.

How does this feature work?

**Edit**:

This [Meta SO question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-does-peer-review-for-edits-work) is similar to mine. It explains the mechanics, but it doesn't address the tag-wiki piece well. ("How can I see proposed edits on a site-wide basis?")

(It also isn't clear if this is fully implemented for this site -- this is a new feature.)

See this [SO blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) for background.

**Edit**: I see them showing up now -- a "1" with a circle around it next to the "tools" link in the toolbar.

Answer (score 2):

It's a part of the newfangled review functionality:

https://money.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits

(It's the right most tab, if you go to the base ../review page.)

Comment: I get a 404, and no tab for it on the review page. As Chris said, maybe the granted the right, but didn't give me the link.

Comment: @bstpierre It's the same for me.  The way I believe it works is we can approve tag wiki edits on tag wiki's we'd normally have access to.  You would have to go to the individual tag wiki page to see the suggested edits there.

Comment: @C. Ross So I guess we can't propose our own wiki tag edits, we can just approve other people's?

Answer (score 0):

I was the one who approved your mortgage tag edit.

I've seen these tag wiki edit requests show up as flags for moderator attention next to the "mod" link in the top bar.  The notification is a number link, but colored different than the abuse-type flags for moderator attention.

As to how *you* can see the edits and approve them, I'm not sure.  Perhaps they did grant the *right* at your rep level, but the missing piece may be a link to the functionality for those folks who don't yet see the "mod" link?

Comment: That would make sense. It could also be that they're low frequency and I just haven't seen them because you or one of the other mods gets there first.